# Vim: delete everything in a line after character without moving cursor in the first place

Tags: vim

Suppose the following line and cursor position:

```
foo = some_func(1 +[ ]2)
                   ^^^
              cursor position
```

Using `di` + `(` I could easily get rid of everything inside the brackets or delete everything to line start or end using `d^` and `d$` respectively, but what would I do if I would like to delete everything that comes after `=`?

The resulting line should be:

```
foo =[ ]
     ^^^
cursor position
```

`dT`+`=` deletes everything until (backwards) the character `=`, but it still leaves `2)` in the line, ending up in:

```
foo =[2])
     ^^^
cursor position
```

I could, of course, jump to `=` first and then use `d$` to delete everything until line ending, but I would prefer a simple shortcut based on current cursor position without the need to move the cursor (if such a shortcut exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>T</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (Jump to after `=`, delete to end of line) is the shortest way, I believe.

You *can* do it without the movement first, but it is considerably more complex: `:s/=\@<=.*//` <kbd>CR</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much, I did really forgot about `t` / `T` for jumping fast jumping in the line. A 3-key shortcut is definitely nice and fast enough :)